# AngularJS scroll down initial

Tags: css, angularjs

I have the following div container:

```
<div class="col-md-8 grid-wrapper-div chatHistory">
...
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.chat .chatHistory {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: 550px;
}
```

and if the page is loaded than the scroll bar should be at bottom -> I use AngularJS.
Is there any possibility to scroll down with css or with AngularJS

**[EDIT]**

I have tried it like this but **chatHistoryContainer.scrollHeight** is undefined. Does anyone know why?
[image: Debug]

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not perform actions on all elements like jQuery selectors, it returns an array like object of all elements. `[elem1, elem2].scrollTop` is obviously not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngInit, which runs upon rendering content and $timeout to postpone scrolling to the next digest cycle in order to wait for the content rendered completely.

```
<div id="chat_history" class="col-md-8 grid-wrapper-div chatHistory" ng-init="scrollToBottom()">
...
</div>

myApp
  .controller(function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.scrollToBottom = function() {
      $timeout(function(){
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat_history");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
      });
    };
  });
```